# iOS9: Universal Links delegate not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios9

I want to open the app when some http url is invoked, if the app is already installed but this delegate is never being called. I follow the link below [link](https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207032266-Setting-Deeplinking-on-iOS9-using-iOS-Universal-Links).

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(void(^)(NSArray * __nullable restorableObjects))restorationHandler
{
    if ([userActivity.activityType isEqualToString:NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb]) {
        NSURL *url = userActivity.webpageURL;
        NSLog(@"url %@",url);
           [self showAlert:@"" :[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[userActivity description]] shouldShow:YES];
        // do something with the URL
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: I want to open the app on some http url if app is installed but this delegate never being called

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons why the `continueUserActivity` is not called back.

1. You need to upload your apple-app-site-association file to your server.
2. Implement your delegate call back method in AppDelegate, which you are already doing
3. Then update the `Associated Domains` section in your app with the domain urls. Make sure you have both [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and example.com

If any of the above is done wrong, you wouldn't get the call back.

If you haven't already, I would strongly recommend you to go through this [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc2015)